# How can we install vi without the vim package in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim, package, text-editor, vi

I want to install only vi in my Ubuntu box. I don't want to install the complete vim package which includes vi. I am trying to reduce the image size of my OS including all the packages so that I have more space to install other packages.

I am open to look into other lightweight text-editor alternatives also but it would be better if I stick with vi.

Comment: ubuntu ships with vi by default. Can you check if it is already installed with `which vi`

Comment: I removed the complete vim package so that I can install only vi, but I was not able to find any way to install only vi.

Comment: What did `which vi` return?

Comment: I don't think you'll uninstall vi by removing vim

Comment: which: no vi in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busybox contains a light vi implementation. I think you can symlink `/usr/bin/vi -> /bin/busybox` or wherever busybox resides in Ubuntu systems. At least this is on my gentoo:

```
(~) file `which vi`
/usr/bin/vi: symbolic link to ../../bin/busybox
```

On Ubuntu (16&18 at least) symlink with: `ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/vi`

If busybox is not installed already it has its own package: `apt install busybox`

Answer (score 2):

You can install vim-tiny package to install vi without vim. Please run the command:

sudo apt-get install vim-tiny

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want `vi` you can find it here: http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/